# ValueError: The truth value of an array ... but it's just an int

Tags: python, python-3.x, valueerror, monte-carlo-tree-search

I have an array `self.N` of ints, and I'm trying to write `self.N[node] +=1`, but whenever I just write `self.N[node]` it gives me a value error for having more than one element, which it can't.

```py
def __init__(self, exploration_weight=1):
    self.Q = defaultdict(int)  # total reward of each node
    self.N = defaultdict(int)  # total visit count for each node
    self.children = dict()  # children of each node
```

```py
def do_rollout(self, node, player):
    "Make the tree one layer better. (Train for one iteration.)"
    print("in rollout")

    "Find an unexplored descendent of `node`"
    path = self._select(node)
    leaf = path[-1]

    "Update the `children` dict with the children of `node`"
    if leaf not in self.children:
        self.children[node] = node.find_children()

    "Send the reward back up to the ancestors of the leaf"
    for node in reversed(path):
        self.N[node] += 1
```

```py
 def _select(self, node):
        "Find an unexplored descendent of `node`"
        path = []
        while True:
            path.append(node)
            if node not in self.children or not self.children[node]:
                # node is either unexplored or terminal
                return path
            unexplored = self.children[node] - self.children.keys()
            if unexplored:
                n = unexplored.pop()
                path.append(n)
                return path
            node = self.children[node]  # descend a layer deeper
```

I expect that `self.N[node] += 1` will simply increment the value of `self.N` at index `node`

I've found in the debugger something seems to be wrong with the keys, but I don't know what.

```py
    (Pdb) self.children[leaf]

    turn:2
        |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
        |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
        |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
        |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
        |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
        |   |   |   |   |   | X | O |
          _   _   _   _   _   _   _
          0   1   2   3   4   5   6
    *** KeyError: turn: 2, done False, winner: None
```

and the node comparator seems not to be working either, but I don't know why:

I've also found that just before it raises the error, the debugger says:

```py
    (pdb) p self.children.keys()
    *** TypeError: 'Node' object is not iterable
```

even though it clearly worked until this point

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_MCTS.py", line 52, in <module>
    agent_wins += play_bot()
  File "test_MCTS.py", line 18, in play_bot
    tree.do_rollout(board, 0) # player 0 is 2nd
  File "/Users/TorSaxberg/.../MCTS_minimal.py", line 50, in do_rollout
    self.N[node] += 1
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

board is a node containing a [6,7] array and methods to fill it

a minimum example:

```py
    from random import randint
    from collections import defaultdict

    Q = defaultdict(int)  # total reward of each node
    N = defaultdict(int)  # total visit count for each node
    children = dict()  # children of each node


    def do_rollout(num):
        "Make the tree one layer better. (Train for one iteration.)"
        print("in rollout")

        "Find an unexplored descendent of `node`"
        path = _select(num)
        leaf = path[-1]

        "Update the `children` dict with the children of `node`"
        if leaf not in children: # a dict()
            children[num] = randint(0,5)

        "Send the reward back up to the ancestors of the leaf"
        for num in reversed(path):
            N[num] += 1 # a dict()

    def _select(num):
        "Find an unexplored descendent of `node`"
        path = []
        while True:
            path.append(num)
            if num not in children or not children[num]:
                return path
            breakpoint()
            unexplored = children[num] - children.keys() # a set()
            if unexplored:
                n = unexplored.pop()
                path.append(n)
                return path
            # descend a layer deeper
            num = children[randint(0,5)]

    num = randint(0,5)
    for _ in range(10):
        do_rollout(num)
```

but i cant get past another TyepError to show the error above

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test_ValueError.py", line 43, in <module>
        do_rollout(num)
      File "test_ValueError.py", line 14, in do_rollout
        path = _select(num)
      File "test_ValueError.py", line 33, in _select
        unexplored = children[num] - children.keys() # a set()
    TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

it's weird because node isn't iterable either (from debugging)
`TypeError: 'Node' object is not iterable`

Comment: Please make a [mre], or at least add the definition of `self.N` and the full error message including traceback.

Comment: I forgot, you also need to at least add the definition of `self._select`.

Comment: Based on the error messge, you'll also need to add the value of `board` for `tree.do_rollout(board, 0)`. Really it would be better if you made a [mre].

Comment: I'll try to put that example together, but first I'll add the other parts you've suggested

Comment: @wjandrea I posted a minimal example. although it runs into a different error, it just show the algorithm flow.

Comment: I've updated this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57541777/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-from-dict-key-comparison